# Why does an empty lambda and constructor with an explicit return cause a compiler error (Java Bug?)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a reproducible test case:

```
public class TestCase {

    private final java.util.function.Consumer<Object> emptyCallback = result -> {};

    public TestCase() {
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new TestCase();
    }
}
```

Using Java 8, update 51 (Oracle JDK). This can't be compiled, using both IntelliJ and javac.

IntelliJ output:

```
Error(6, 7): java: variable result might not have been initialized
```

javac output:

```
TestCase.java:6: error: Variable result might not have been initialized
        return;
        ^
1 error
```

Now what is strange, is that removing `return;` or the `Consumer` will fix the error. Is this a java bug, or is there something of the language design that I am missing here?

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [How can a constructor return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574276/java-how-can-a-constructor-return-a-value), this is actually a constructor and isn't about the return value of constructor but variable initialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How can a constructor return a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574276/java-how-can-a-constructor-return-a-value)

Comment: Why would you `return` from a constructor?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this is a very watered down reproducible example from a different issue,where upon calling System#exit the constructor should have ceased immediately.

Comment: I see your edit, and unless Java 8 has this feature and I am not aware, you simply can't return from a Constructor

Comment: @cricket_007 sure you can, just as long as there isn't a field with a lambda (according to the bug report below). `return` has always been supported in the constructor.

Comment: I see... I suppose the JLS link below clarifies that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find an official bug report [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077667). The issue is fixed in Java 9.

---

[You can `return` inside a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)

> A return statement returns control to the invoker of a method (§8.4,
>   §15.12) or constructor (§8.8, §15.9).

Comment: Seems like it's known, so at least I don't have to write up a massive bug report on oracle. Yay!